# Сокращение выражения

Tags: android, kotlin

Здравствуйте! Написал такое выражение:

```
name = findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView
name!!.text = stringFormatter.formatString(R.string.name, model!!.title)
```

Но мне кажется, что оно слишком длинное. Подскажи, как можно его сократить? Заранее спасибо.

Пробую использовать  android extenssions:

```
name?.setText(R.id.name)
name?.text = stringFormatter.formatString(R.string.name, model?.title)
```

Текст не отображается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно с помощью [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) примерно следующим образом:

```
textView.setText("Hello, world!")
// Instead of findView(R.id.textView) as TextView
```

Более подробно найдёте в самой ссылке официальной документации.

Comment: обновил вопрос, взгляните пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообще по хорошему Вам стоит лишь оставить строчку `        name?.text = stringFormatter.formatString(R.string.name, model?.title)
` а также если Вы объявляли переменную ДО то удалить и там. Возможно этот конфликт перекрывает.

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо, в самом начале объявлял переменную.